# Implement Oauth as provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

How do you implement oauth as a provider in c#?

There is a c# clas. For it, here http://oauth.net/code/
 but I need to know how do I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about a membership provider, there is a previous discussion here:

- [oAuth ASP.NET Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209031/oauth-asp-net-membership-provider)

If you mean as a third-party API access provider, there is an example here:

- [Twitter oAuth with .NET](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/?p=681)

Comment: cool, btw as a provider who are the "Consumer key" and "Consumer secret" generated?

Comment: I don't think that is specified by OpenAuth, but it is advisable to generate a secret that is reasonably long and random.  They key is often just a web address of the consumer or something else to make it easy to identify the consumer in your records.