# Share Users data to the Clients using dot net OAuth - MVC3/4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I have a website, which contains huge user information. I would like to share these users information using OAuth to third parties users/websites. I found some of the questions related to my requirement, but those were not clear for me. ([oAuth ASP.NET Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209031/oauth-asp-net-membership-provider)). I would like to use dot net OAuth for authentication. My Queries are as follows.

1. How we can implement an authentication mechanism when the client request an API service.
   For authentication probably client may need some sort of consumers keys. How they will get 
   those keys. Any registration is needed ?
2. Do I need to manually maintain any data base for storing the consumers keys/Secret Keys/
   Token Detais Or will it handled Automatically.

I have only rough idea about this kind of authentication. So detailed help will be helpful for me.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to consider something simpler unless you really need all the features of OAuth. See [OAuth 2.0 - Looking Back and Moving On](http://vimeo.com/52882780)

Comment: Right now I dont need all the features of OAuth. But eventually I may need all. So can't consider another option.

Comment: Well then start reading the [OAuth 2.0 RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) because it'll be a long painful journey.

Comment: You need to handle EVERYTHING yourself since your rollng out your own OAuth provider.