# Is it possible to create a OAuth 2.0 Provider in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

So far I have found zero articles on how.  Only for php.

Not sure if  ASP.Net DotNetOpenOauth has the capabilities of doing so.

Comment: Thi may help [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209031/oauth-asp-net-membership-provider

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries